# Pointer and character array

Tags: c, pointers

Hello Everyone I just want to clarify a doubt regarding pointers.So that I can know whether I understood it correctly or not.

```
void main ()
{
char c[10]="COMPUTERS";
printf("The first is %d\n",c);         //1
printf("The second is %f\n",c);        //2
printf("The third is %u\n",c);         //3
printf("The fourth is %s\n",c);        //4
printf("The fifth is %c\n",c);         //5
}
```

The first printf will print the address of first location of character array 'c',

Similarly second printf will also try to print the address in float form.

The third printf will print the address again.

While the fourth printf will print the character array.

My doubt is associated with the 5th printf. It is printing random values or sometimes no values is it because the value of 'c' is memory address of first character of array 'c' and I am trying to print that value as a character?

Comment: Yes `c` is an address and printing it as a character is weird. There is some casting that is applied (the details are not interesting here) so that an ASCII code is determined by transforming the address value. It is almost a non-sense and can generate weird chars (invisible ones, control ones, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of those prints are undefined behavior except the `%s` one. the weird behavior you are seeing with `%c` format specifier is due to underlying casts on the adress of the pointer which can change from running it one time to the next.

if you want to print out the adress the pointer points to use `%p` like this:

```
printf("address: %p\n", (void *)c);
```

Comment: also, an explicit cast to `void *` is necessary because `printf` is variadic.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: How could a cast change the object code here? Or did you mean, in order to prevent compilation warning for compilers that can identify this on `printf`'s first argument?

Comment: @rowan.G: On the same system, different pointer types have the same size. But if you port your code between different systems (for example, from 32-bit to 64-bit), then you might get different behavior as a result of different pointer size (for example, from 4 bytes to 8 bytes).

Comment: @barakmanos `c` has type `char[10]`. When passed to a function, it's implicitly converted to type `char *`. Since `printf()` is variadic, this type is not further converted to `void *` implicitly, despite the fact that `%p` expects a parameter of type `void *` (simply because this fact can't easily be deduced at compile time without intrinsics). This means that passing the parameter without conversion results in undefined behavior, so the compiler can do whatever it pleases. In contrast, when the cast is included, the call has well-defined behavior, so the compiler has to emit correct code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Of course, for `printf` it may well change the object code, even if you cast from a 32-bit integer to a 64-bit integer... My mistake...

Answer (score 1):

(These are not "doubts", they are questions or uncertainties perhaps).

All of those except `%s` are undefined behavior, since they all mis-match the actual type of the value provided (`char *`) with the formatting specifier.

Comment: Plus one for the grammatical correction. (the system doesn't let me spell it out for some reason – why?)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("The fifth is %c\n",c[0]);
```

This makes sense. Printing the first character of the array.
Trying to print the address just as a character makes no sense.

Only this `printf()` is good

```
printf("The fourth is %s\n",c);
```

The rest of the `printf()'s` have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> The first printf will print the address of first location of character array 'c',

Strictly speaking, the first printf will invoke undefined behavior since you are using the wrong format specifier to print a pointer. But yeah it will *probably* print the address on most systems.

> Similarly second printf will also try to print the address in float form.

No it will just give you some binary goo. You never convert the address to a float format, you only attempt to print it as if it was. This is completely undefined behavior.

> The third printf will print the address again.

Same as 1. Undefined behavior, but yeah, it will probably print the address...

> While the fourth printf will print the character array.

Yes.

> My doubt is associated with the 5th printf. It is printing random values or sometimes no values is it because the value of 'c' is memory address of first character of array 'c' and I am trying to print that value as a character?

Again, undefined behavior. It can print anything.

Comment: To be more exact, the first `printf` will print the numeric value of the address on systems where the size of a pointer is the same a the size of an `int`, that is, practically speaking, all modern 32-bit systems.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy `s/will/can/g`. I've seen aggressive optimizers doing funny things with code containing UB that "should obviously work"…

Comment: As to the second `printf`, it will print either an arbitrary floating-point value, or `+INF`, or `-INF`, or `NAN`. IIRC, there are no bit combinations in IEEE 754 which have no valid interpretation, and all major systems base their representation of `double` on IEEE 754.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, theoretically true, but I'd still rather write 'will'. I have never seen an optimizer that would optimize into the internals of complex standard library functions such as `printf`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy not internals, but the call. LLVm can do this. If it deduces that the call results in UB, then it can remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical analysis:

```
printf("The first is %d\n",c);  // undefined behavior by the standard
printf("The second is %f\n",c); // undefined behavior by the standard
printf("The third is %u\n",c);  // undefined behavior by the standard
printf("The fifth is %c\n",c);  // undefined behavior by the standard
```

Practical analysis:

```
printf("The first is %d\n",c);  // requires sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int)
printf("The second is %f\n",c); // requires sizeof(void*) == sizeof(double)
printf("The third is %u\n",c);  // requires sizeof(void*) == sizeof(unsigned int)
printf("The fifth is %c\n",c);  // different between big-endian and little-endian
```

Detailed practical analysis:

- `sizeof(void*) < sizeof(...)` will potentially yield a memory access violation during runtime
- `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(...)` will yield different printout between big-endian and little-endian